# The fourth power (Juzuk)

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence

In 1939 Juzuk described a way to generate the fourth powers of natural numbers. 
Group the natural numbers like this:

```
1   2 3   4 5 6   7 8 9 10   11 12 13 14 15   ...
```

Scratch each second group:

```
1   4 5 6   11 12 13 14 15 ...
```

The sum of the *n* remaining groups is *n***4.

- **Input**: none
- **Task**: print the fourth powers upto 100**4, using Juzuk's method.
- **Output**:

  0 (optional)
  1
  16
  81
  ...
  100000000

Comment: While I find it acceptable to forbid language specificities that make it too easy to solve a problem, I'm not fond of that “use Juzuk’s method” rule. Is it allowed to take the `n-1` result in account when computing for `n`? Is it allowed to simplify integer sums using the `n(n+1)/2` formula? When is it no longer Juzuk’s method?

Comment: Rhetorical questions?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because "implement Juzuk's algorithm" is an unobservable requirement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### J, <s>40</s> 38 (*not* summing unneeded)

```
+/\+/"1(+:i.100){(#~i.201)[/.>:i.20100
```

### J, 30 (summing unneeded)

```
+/\_2{.\(#~i.201)+//.>:i.20100
```

Answer (score 4):

### J, 33

```
~.+/\(#~i.200)(+/*2|#)/.1+i.2!200
```

Comment: Summing the groups you'll scratch later is a nice codesize optimization, but in an "implement it this way" context, I feel robbed ;)

Comment: @JB: well... I *am* using Juzuk's method, I just sum zeros :)

Answer (score 3):

**Haskell, 78**

```
print[sum$concat$take x[take x$drop(sum[1..x-1])[1..]|x<-[1,3..]]|x<-[0..100]]
[0,1,16,81,256,625,1296,2401,4096,6561,10000,14641,20736,28561,38416,50625,65536,...
```

Hope the slightly different output formatting is ok. There's probably a much better way to write this in Haskell, but I felt like solving this in a language I don't often use.

Answer (score 3):

### Python 2, 68

Quick and dirty Python solution:

```python
s=0
for n in range(100):s+=sum(range(2*n*n+n+1,2*n*n+3*n+2));print s
```